# How to customize percentage increments of an element's width via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, event-handling, addeventlistener

I am having trouble changing the width of an element each time on click.
Right now, everytime the function is run, the width increases by 1%.

I want to be able to pass in a parameter/argument in the function that will allow me to customize the percentage increments on click.

i.e. have the percentage increase by 5's every click, or increase the percentage by 10's or 25's on click.

Here is the function I have so far:

```
function progressBar(clickElement){
   document.getElementById(clickElement).onclick = function(){
      var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
      var current_width = progress.style.width.replace("%", " ");
      var currentWidth = document.getElementById("currentWidth");
      current_width = (current_width > 100) ? 100 : current_width;
      currentWidth.innerHTML = "Progress: " + current_width++ + "%";
      progress.style.width = parseInt(current_width) + "%";
   }
}
```

note this line of code:

```
   var current_width = progress.style.width.replace("%", " ");
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="loader">
      <div id="progress"></div>
</div>
<div id="currentWidth"></div>
<input id="increase" type="submit" value="Increase">
```

What can I change or add to this function that will allow me to customize the percentage increments?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you provide the html?

Comment: I have updated the question with the HTML

Comment: progress always starts from 0 or it could be another value (e.g 17%)?. What should happen if you are at 97% and add 5%?

Comment: I am building a clicking game where the goal is reached at various intervals of 5 (i.e. level 1: 5 clicks, level 2: 25 clicks). So my percentage will never be at 97%, as I hope it will reflective of how many clicks is required for each level. Ex: level 1: 5 clicks, each click = 25% of the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(didnt see your html so i made my own)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>click game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="info">Progress: 0%</div>
    <div id="progress" style="width:0%;height:100px;border:1px solid black;"></div>
    <button id="increase100">1 click needed</button>
    <button id="increase20">5 clicks needed</button>
    <button id="increase4">25 clicks needed</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let info = document.getElementById("info");
        let progress = document.getElementById("progress");
        function makedynamic(button, neededclicks) {
            let stepsize = 100 / neededclicks;
            document.getElementById(button).onclick = function() {
                let width = progress.style.width.replace("%", "");
                width = parseInt(width) + stepsize;
                if (width >= 100) {
                    progress.style.width = "100%";
                    info.innerHTML = stepsize > 10 ? "You made it!" : "ouch, my fingerrrrs";
                } else {
                    width = width +"%";
                    progress.style.width = width;
                    info.innerHTML = "Progress: " + width;
                }
            }
        }
        makedynamic('increase100',1);
        makedynamic('increase20',5);
        makedynamic('increase4',25);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After understanding the problem better:

Try separating the display from the game logic, right now you are saving the game state inside your html elements, which is not ideal. Something like this:

```
// Place this somewhere where it's accessible to you other game logic.
var INCREASE = 5;
var gameState = {
    progress: 1,
}

// Update the actual game state.
function updateProgress(clickElement, gameState) {
    gameState.progress *= INCREASE;
    displayProgress(clickElement, gameState.progress);
}

// displayProgress now only displays, it is not used to store the progress.
function displayProgress(clickElement, progress){
   document.getElementById(clickElement).onclick = function(){
      var progress = document.getElementById("progress");
      currentWidth.innerHTML = "Progress: " + progress + "%";
      progress.style.width = parseInt(progress) + "%";
   }
}
```

This makes a lot more sense from a design perspective.

Comment: If i wanted multiples of 5, lets say. Can it be like this: current_width *= increase amount; ?

Comment: If you wanted to increase by 5, you would pass 5 as a parameter. progressBar(yourElement, 5). Multiplying current_width by 5 would not increase it by five, but would make it five times wider than before, each time you clicked it.

Comment: Please let me know if it's not clear and I could try to elaborate

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work the way that I hoped it would :(
I am building a clicking game where the goal is reached at various intervals of 5 (i.e. level 1: 5 clicks, level 2: 25 clicks). I would like it to be reflective of how many clicks is required for each level. Ex: level 1: 5 clicks, each click = 25% of the progress.

Comment: stepsize = 100 / neededclicks